# Spring Data REST, MVC QueryDSL bindings | simulate default bindings

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have web application with Spring Data REST enabled and came across [Querydsl web support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe)

I also defined repository as follows:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long>, 
                                        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Order> {}
```

and Order entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Order extends AbstractEntity {

    private final Location location;
    private final LocalDateTime orderedDate;
    private Status status;

    @OrderColumn
    @Column(unique = true)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public enum Status {
        PAYMENT_EXPECTED,
        PAID,
        PREPARING,
        READY,
        TAKEN;
    }
}
```

The documentation states:

```
The default binding is as follows:

Object on simple properties as eq.

Object on collection like properties as contains.

Collection on simple properties as in.
```

If I want to simulate first binding, I can issue e.g.

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
http://localhost:8080/api/orders?status=READY
```

then server side will convert request param into querydsl predicate `order.status = READY`

I am having hard time getting my head around 2 other cases.

How should request params look like to have correct predicates created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of the 2nd type would be:

http://localhost:8080/api/orders?status=PAID&status=READY

This is similar to a JPQL in clause. Give me all Orders where the status is either PAID **or** READY

An example of the 3rd type would be:

http://localhost:8080/api/orders?lineItems=http://localhost:8080/api/lineItems/1

This is similar to a JPQL contains clause. Give me all Orders whose lineItems contains the specified Object (the unique URI for the resource is specified as the request param).

Comment: 2nd works for me.
3rd one, I had to use http://localhost:8080/api/orders?lineItems=LINE_ITEM_ID

I was getting conversion exception for your example

Comment: I think it probably depends on whether Line Items is exposed as a Rest Resource. If so then you would use the URI style rather than your style. Can you try quickly?

Comment: LineItems are not exposed as rest resouce, because Order is an aggregate root which contain them. I have only OrderRepository exposed as Rest Resource.

Comment: I tested one to many relationship on another project where both entities are exposed as rest resources and I use ID only. URI doesn't work